# Reload view after received notification

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5, notifications

I have a tab bar controller with two views. When i press a button in my second view, i send a notification to my first view and i want my first view to reload its data. But if i switch over to my first view from my second view, the first view data hasn't been reloaded. I'm using AQGridview, btw.

//firstView.m

```
-(void) reloadGridView: (NSNotification *)notification
{
[_gridView reloadData];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{  
//notification for added exercise
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadGridView:) name:@"reloadGridView" object:nil];
}
```

//secondView.m

```
 - (IBAction)AddExercise:(id)sender 
 {
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"reloadGridView" object: nil];
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably better to call the reloadData from the viewDidAppear in the first tab rather than using notifications.